# Resolving UsersController#show Couldn't find User with 'id'=1when that id was previously deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am following Michael Hartl's tutorial.  I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show
Couldn't find User with 'id'=1

Extracted source (around line #155)
    record = s.execute([id], self, connection).first
    unless record
      raise RecordNotFound, "Couldn't find #{name} with '#{primary_key}'=#{id}"
    end
    record
  rescue RangeError
```

Already have tried bundle install and restarted the server because the initial error related to the bcrypt Gemfile (using v 3.1.7).

Running rails console and inputing User.find(1) yields no user. However, User.all in rails c does reveal that I have one user but it has an id: 2 (the very first user I made was likely deleted during prior test runs).

app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

 def show
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end

 def new
 end
end
```

app/config/routes.rb
    Rails.application.routes.draw do

```
  get 'users/new'

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  resources :users

end
```

Currently URL/users/2 displays as expected
with the debug showing:

```
 --- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
 controller: users
 action: show
 id: '2'
```

However, this is not the case for id: 1 since it has previously been destoryed.

Is it possible to even reassign an id in the database after it has been created (i.e. to a prior id like 1 or any other arbitrary assignment)?

Thanks!

Comment: Huh? Not sure what's the question here. User 1 doesn't exist anymore. Use the one that you have.

Comment: Thanks!  I just clarified the question a bit more: Essentially, I want to know if it is possible to rename the id in the database once it has been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to care about the data you have deleted from the database. And you'll never need to visit a "show" view by type urls in your browser. For example, you may want to create an index view, showing all the users.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end
end

<% # "app/views/users/index.html.erb" %>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= link_to "user.name", users_path(user) %>
<% end %>
```

When you click the links in the index page, Rails will automatically find the user's id and redirect you to the right page.

If you do want to type some url like "yourlocalhost/users/1" in your browser, it's reasonable to get the error you mentioned. Instead of trying to make that url working as you expected, you'd better add some error handling. For example, rescue that error to redirect your users to some page, then show them a notice: "Sorry man, that page is not exist, please visit other page. :P"

Generally, it's not a good idea to reuse ids in database which you have freed by deleting record. Because it's very easy to cause problems. For example, if you have other tables in your database, with a "user_id" column. It may have conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to assign a new value to the id of a record and save it.

But this is a very bad practice.

First, it will pretty much ruin your record associations which are all based on your record's primary key.

Second, it can lead to duplicate primary keys, either by assigning an id that will be used at a later point or by assigning an id already in use. Your DB will therefore disallow saving the record, either now or later.

The point of a primary key is that it has NO inherent meaning or significance other than being a unique identifer to the record... so you should never care about the value or characteristics of the primary key and so you should never have any need to change it.

Answer (score 1):

In my oppinion, you have to ovoid your nil value by passing condition to redirect into your user index page. This way is usual way.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
     if @user.nil?
        redirect_to users_path
     end
  end

  def new
  end
end
```

Try to get user know to get right data because when passing into another id it will get unexpected data that user wanted